Percentages comparison and order of magnitude
maybe this is a too simple question.
Suppose to have to cases:
case 1: number of patients/Universe of patients: 63.080/1.335.636 = 4.7%
case 2: number of patients/Universe of patients: 5.840.431/59.030.133 = 9.8%
How can I compare the two percentages? in other words, maybe they are not so different if it is possible to set the numerator and the denominator of case 1 to have the same order of magnitude of case 2 or better the viceversa. As they are, of course they are different because the order of magnitude is different.
Can anyone help me please?
Thank you in advence

Not a full answer, but as a general rule of thumb, N=100 will let you estimate a proportion within +/- 10 percentage points, N=500 gets you within 5 points, N=1000 gets you within 3% of the true value, and N=10000 within 1%. With N=1 million, the observed estimate is very likely to be within 0.1% of the true percentage.

I will interpret your proportions and your "universe of patients" as "a certain number of patients -63,080 for case 1- was found to have some attribute, out of a sample of studied patients (or studied patient records) of a certain size -1,335,636 for your case1-". This is to say that I will not consider the use of finite populations corrections (and in any case, your proportions are rather small compared to the total population).
What you have are 2 proportions, which you want to compare. Bottom line, there are a number of solutions to this; z-test of 2 proportions, $\chi^2$ test of independence (which gives you the exact same p-value as the z-test), and Fisher exact.
Your 2 proportions can be summarized in a 2x2 table, so-called contingency matrix (or table). In your case it would look like
$\begin {matrix} case1 & case2 \\ 63080 & 1272556 \\ 5840431 & 53189702\end {matrix}$.
You could first run a z-test of 2 proportions (e.g. see here; and you can find an online calculator here).
Or you can run a $chi^2$ test (e.g. see here for explanations, and you can find an online calculator here).
Note that both tests will give you exactly the same p-value, and that the $chi^2$ statistic will be the square of the z statistic. These 2 tests, even though they approach the problem differently, are in fact one and the same.
Or you can run a Fisher-exact test (e.g. see here, or use this link for an online calculator). Now some software may have problems with your sample, as the numbers are rather large (to say the least) and Fisher exact involves computing factorials.
Last, you could also compute exact binomial confidence intervals for the 2 proportions (aka Clopper Pearson interval); e.g. see here, and here for an online calculator. If the 2 confidence intervals do not overlap (and here, they will not), then the 2 proportions are statistically different. Note that this last approach (non overlapping CI's) is a sufficient condition, but not necessary; in more borderline cases, it will not work as well as the previous approaches. But in your particular case, you are so far from borderline that it will. I mention it more for pedagogical reasons, as many students find confidence intervals more intuitive than p-values (and confidence intervals can be visualized).
BTW, in your specific case, the 2 proportions are "enormously" statistically significantly different, due to the very large sample sizes (and the fact that 1 is ~twice the other). Any of the above tests will leave no doubt about this.

The other current answer addresses what kind of tests you could use. In your specific case, I'd argue that given the number of observations in each group, it may not be necessary to conduct a test at all to tell there's a difference between the two groups. If you're new to statistics, you'll eventually notice that very large sample sizes can lead to small p-values even with a trivial effect size.
Second, if you're interested in knowing why it is not a good idea to change the original counts in your data (in order to get the same denominator in both groups, like you suggest), it is because you would be either destroying information, or inventing information that is not here. Therefore, tests would not be able to evaluate correctly the uncertainty that your real, true data reflect, making the p-value you get unreliable.
Even if with your number of observations I suspect you wouldn't reach a very different conclusion ("there's a difference between the two groups") no matter if you altered or not the data, artificially changing the counts like you suggest is not a correct procedure. Tests should be able to take into account different sizes between the groups you're comparing, so there is no reason to alter the data*.
That being said, the intuition you have ("two groups of equal sizes must be somehow better for statistical analysis") is not completely wild, because having groups of equal sizes may give you better statistical power than groups of unequal size (this is assuming the same total number of observations in the "equal" and "unequal" scenarios). However, the correct way of getting groups of equal sizes in the first place is to plan it at the design stage of your study, i.e. you have to plan for collecting groups of equal sizes. To make correct inferences, you can't alter the data like you suggest once you collected it.

* Some tests may be badly behaved with unequal sample sizes, like the two-sample t-test assuming equal variance (if the variance is in fact very different between the two groups), but the correct way to address this kind of situation is to use a correction or another test, not to destroy or to alter data.
